# Webflux Http 404 Response when header is added to Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am currently trying to shift my application from spring boot 1.5.x to 2.x.x on reactive stack. I am facing a kinda weird problem that I can't figure out. Hope someone knows the solution to this.

I implemented an api to receive a user jwt token as "Authorization" field on the header. The api is a POST method that receives a certain json data from the user in the body, goes to the backend and processes it.
The unfortunate thing is i keep getting a http 404 error when i add in the header, a normal 200 when i remove it in postman. 
Here is my controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@Slf4j
public class UserHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @Autowired
    private Utility utility;

    @PostMapping("/updateLink")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> addNewAccountLinkAPI(@RequestHeader(name="Authorization") String id, @RequestBody UpdateAccountLink request){
        return Mono.just(request)
                .flatMap(s -> service.addNewAccountLink(s))
                .flatMap(s -> ok().body(BodyInserters.fromObject(new RespWrap("Success", new Date(), null, s))))
                .switchIfEmpty(badRequest().body(BodyInserters.fromObject(new RespWrap("Failed", new Date(), "Failed to create new link", null))));
    }
}
```

Here is my simple security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableWebFlux
public class ResourceServerConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, FirebaseAuthenticationManager manager) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please point me out on the problem. This sure seems like a lack of config problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues with your code snippets.

First, you shouldn't add `@EnableWebFlux` as it completely disables the auto-configuration done by Spring Boot. Same goes for `@EnableWebMvc` in a Spring MVC application.

Second, you're mixing WebFlux annotations and WebFlux functional. The annotations you're using are fine, but the `ServerResponse` type should only be used [when writing functional handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn). You should try instead here to use `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: thanks. This was a snippet typed while i was shifting between functional and annotations. turns out it was postman's issue that kept giving me the problem. created a new tab and it worked.